# Can a child SBT project get dependencies from its parent?

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

Let's say I have two SBT projects, one that contains a Java-based Play! web application and one containing supporting business logic. The Play! app is the parent project and its build.sbt looks something like this:

```
lazy val support = project.in(file("support"))

lazy val web = project.in(file(".")).aggregate(support).dependsOn(support)
```

There are dependencies that are common to both projects, Guava for example. Currently I have to declare the dependency on Guava twice, once in the parent project and once in the "support" project. Is there any way I can declare that dependency once, in the parent project, and have it available everywhere, kind of like how Maven's parent POMs work? Or am I just stuck having to repeat myself all over the place?

Comment: Why not create a common subproject with only that deps (ex Guava) and make both support and web depend on common?